# Adding Shaders To Mapped Texture

Tags: shaders

So I used Agisoft Photoscan to render a model
it output a texture that is mapped to different sections of my model

My example:

I have a bunny's head and body

Texture1 is mapped to the bunnies eyes, head, and ears

I want it so that the bunny's eyes have a glossy shader applied to them WHILE maintaining the original mapped texture (kinda combining the mapped portion of the texture with a glossy shader) while avoiding making the rest of the head and ears glossy as well?

Comment: You can combine a whatever shader you have now, with a glossy shader, either with an add shader node or with a mix shader and some other mapping to control the mix. Can you please add a few images of what you have so that we can help you better?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this post helpful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853

Answer (score 0):

Put an alpha channel on the texture where you want it to be glossy, then use a color ramp node to mix between your original shader and a glossy shader.